# What is maximum size of any memory segment goes in real life coding?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, x86, segmentation-fault

I'm reading about the x86, In that they have mentioned segment size can go upto 4GB (in 32-bit) architecture.

Does anybody knows or experienced the segment size going beyond limit? 
Or 
upto what limit segment size goes in practical life?
 and 
If it goes beyond the max limit then, it is breaked into segments of different sizes then,  how does the switching between the segments is managed? If RAM is smaller to accomodate the more than one segment

Comment: `segmentation-fault` is irrelevant tag for your question

Comment: You are mixing a few concepts. E.g. 4GB is the maximum memory of 32bit system, not of a segment/page or what ever other way of partitioning it, but the whole lot. 2³² = 4G and that is your lot. Linux/Unix/Nt etc cut this up into pages. Pages can be adjacent, so making up a bigger area of memory.

Comment: If it goes beyond the limit, then it was not the limit.

Comment: Thanks, But "http://www.singlix.com/trdos/runix/yang/Protected Mode Software Architecture.pdf" this book tells that max size of segment can be 4GB (page 112)- Granularity Bit concept, Correct me If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system will not use more memory than it can handle in its allocation table.

Since the maximum number of bytes that can be represented with 32 bits is 4 294 967 296, that limits the memory to 4GB.  On 64 bit systems, the maximum would therefore be 18 446 744 073 709 551 616 bytes (16 777 216 TB) which will obviously not be an issue for decades.  The memory limitations on 64 bit systems depend more on how much memory the hardware can actively handle.

Note that maximum file size often suffers from the same limitation but some systems implemented ways to overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

The design of most modern operating systems employs flat memory model where the segments concept introduced with Intel 80286 is not in use and Linux among them.

The `OS kernel` requires the user process memory space to be directly addressable by the kernel in favor of performance, so the 2^32 address space is split between the kernel and a user space process. For 32bit Linux this ratio is 1:3 - the upper 1G of virtual address space is reserved for the kernel and drivers while the lower 3G of virtual address space is reserved for a process.

For many tasks 3G of RAM is more than enough. However, there are applications that have direct dependence between addressable (and physically available) RAM and their performance. The good examples are [RDBMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), different data analysis, image processing, scientific calculations, e.t.c.